# CI / CD Pipeline - Azure Result Update

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have created my Build definition and was able to execute the scripts. But we have scripts (We have used Rest API's) to update the results in Azure. But we are gettign error message while running in pipeline stating that Test Plan does not exists even though the test plan exists. Error message is shown below

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.d__26`1.MoveNext()
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
    at Automation.Infrastructure.Log.UpdateTestInMTM.UpdateTest(String mtmCollectionUri, String mtmProjectName, String mtmUserName, String mtmPassword, String mtmDomain, String mtmTestPlanId, String mtmConfigurationId, String mtmTestSuiteId, String testCaseId, String outcome)
 ---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi.TestObjectNotFoundException: Test plan 223845 not found.
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__46.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__43`1.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.d__27`1.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__26`1.MoveNext()<---
  Exception caught.

Comment: This is a common error message. We cannot accurately locate the source of the error and display. `Just to know Test plan 223845 not found` . Can you tell us what you are doing and are you using rest api? Can you share your code? Hide your personal information

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?